# Nginx/Apache not accessible from outside, SSH is accessible. Firewall disabled

Tags: apache-2.2, networking, nginx, routing

I have ports 37000-37100 redirected to my computer.  SSH is accessible when listening on any of these ports (by default I'm using 37022, but tried on 37080 and it's OK).

I can only access Nginx on a local IP (example: http : // 192 .168 .49 .198 : 37080), though. When I try to connect from outside (http : // our_network's_ip:37080), the browser times out after a while.  PLEASE READ UPDATE BELOW.
I installed Apache just to make sure and it's the same. Stock install, only ports are changed.

The UTF is disabled.

I've done it a hundred times on various home networks and it always worked.  This time it's an office network and I'm not the person who configures the router.  I'd say the problem's there, but SSH is working... .

Ubuntu 12.10.

Any ideas?

UPDATE: actually I can access my computer from outside networks, I only can't access my computer FROM my own network when I use my network's "external" IP.

Answer (score 0):

On your host where the Nginx runs, try using tcpdump to monitor if there are any packets arriving on your server where you expect them. Otherwise the problem is almost certainly some other configuration like in the router or whatever other network devices you have.

for example to see packets on tcp port 37080 it would be

```
tcpdump -i any tcp port 37080
```

Comment: I've tried it and it doesn't show any traffic. There's more info, though, please see UPDATE in the original post.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like NAT is setup on the router with a specified port number for http
Its the only thing I can think of off the cuff
To be honest, you do not make it clear where your network is in relation to your work network

```
show ip nat translations
Pro Inside global      Inside local       Outside local      Outside global
tcp 172.16.10.8:80     172.16.10.8:8080   ---                ---
```

Answer (score 0):

I would guess, it was a NAT problem.

Let's say the network's gateway had a public IP `gat_public_ip` and a private IP `192.168.49.1`. The gateway was configured with a simple `DNAT` rule from ports `37000-37100` of `gat_public_ip` to the OP's private IP `192.168.49.198`.

When we try to connect from the internal network, let's say `192.168.49.2` port `1234` to port `37000` of `gat_public_ip` the following happens:

- the SYN packet with source `192.168.49.2:1234` and destination `gat_public_ip:37000` exits the internal host,
- the gateway applies the DNAT and resends the packet on the internal network: source `192.168.49.2:1234` and destination `192.168.49.198:37000`,
- the OP's workstation answers with a SYN/ACK: source `192.168.49.198:37000` and destination `192.168.49.2:1234`, which is sent directly to the initiating host.
- the kernel of `192.168.49.21 drops the SYN/ACK since it never sent anything to`192.168.49.198:37000` (it is unaware of the DNAT on the gateway).

The DNAT works correctly, when connecting from the outside: the source address of the packet is not on the internal network `192.168.49/24` and OP's workstation sends the answer to the gateway, which reverses the DNAT.